# is there a way to decipher a given encoding?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, unicode-normalization

On Twitter, this user: https://twitter.com/Rockprincess818

seems to have used creative encoding techniques to achieve special formatting:

They list their name as:

And their bio as:

'     . '   .

None of this seems to be a standard encoding (nor even English -- though I could be wrong about this).

My questions:

1. What did they do to achieve this special formatting?
2. How does one decipher such non-normal text to understand what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There are many online generators (eg. [this one](https://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi?text=This%20is%20pretty%20fun%20too.%20Do%20something%20for%20your%20group%20tag) or [this one](https://lingojam.com/CursiveTextGenerator)) that let users convert normal text to some fancy graphical representation by replacing Latin alphabet letters with similar-looking Unicode symbols.

2) The most obvious way to decipher such text back to normal Latin characters would be to try to find which tools the user uses and what mappings those tools employ. You could then map the fancy Unicode codepoints back to Latin characters. You could find the mappings eg. by converting "`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`" to "cursive" with those tools and analyzing the output.

Answer (score 1):

The Unicode standard has a concept of [compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence), which allows some codepoints to be defined as equivalent to others.  Given the strings in the question, the NFKC normalisation (Normalization Form Compatibility Composition) can be applied to obtain the equivalent latin characters. Programming languages may provide tools to apply normalisation programmatically.

In javascript, the [string.normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) method may be used

```javascript
name = ''
""
bio = "'     . '   ."
"'     . '   ."
name.normalize('NFKC')
"Lisa"
bio.normalize('NFKC')
"I'm not here for your amusement. You're here for mine."
```

In python, the [unicodedata.normalize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) function may be used

```python3
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> name = ''
>>> bio = "'     . '   ."
>>> ud.normalize('NFKC', name)
'Lisa'
>>> ud.normalize('NFKC', bio)
"I'm not here for your amusement. You're here for mine."
```